# WCF Data Services Expand as Linq Statement

Tags: c#, wcf, linq, wcf-data-services, expand

at the moment I am trying myself with WCF Data Services. Now I am trying to query my Servie for some objects similar to the EF ( which is my datasource of the Service ) with an Include Statement, to get an objecttree.

My statement looks like this at this moment :

```
var query = this.Entities.Veranstaltung.Expand( "VeranstaltungMaterial/Material/Template" ).Expand( "Ort,Dozent" );

var k = query.Where( z => z.DauerTage > 5 && z.TemplateID == null );
```

Is it possible to write the Expandstatement via LINQ so it gets translated automatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gert's answer is correct, just wanted to expand on it (and can't fit it into a comment):
You can express even the first query with the Expand just using LINQ:

```
Order_Details.Take(1).Select(od =>
    new Order_Detail
    {
        Order = new Order
        {
            Customer = od.Order.Customer
        },
        Product = new Product
        {
            Order_Details = od.Product.Order_Details
        },
    });
```

You can do a similar trick with m:n relationships. This sample follows a 1:n relationship but from the opposite direction:

```
Customers.Select(c =>
    new Customer
    {
        Orders = c.Orders.Select(o =>
            new Order
            {
                Order_Details = o.Order_Details
            });
    });
```

This is equivalent to ~/Customers?$expand=Orders/Order_Details&$select=Orders/Order_Details.

Comment: Well that's not a trick but it is an extra roundtrip to the server for each entity in a collection. I wanted to avoid exactly this :(

Comment: No it's not a roundtrip. WCF DS Client LINQ provider never translates an expression into multiple requests. If it can't do it in one request it will fail the translation. You can verify by storing the result of the above expression in a variable and call ToString on it. It will return you the URL query which is to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your question is: can I get to the navigation properties through regular linq statements in stead of the WCF-DS-specific `Expand` statement? If so, the answer is "yes, we can".

Of course I can't use your example but if I connect to the Northwind OData service<sup>1</sup> I can do:

```
Order_Details.Expand("Order/Customer").Expand("Product/Order_Details").Take (1)
```

or

```
Order_Details.Take(1).Select(o => 
                      new { o.Order.Customer, o.Product.Order_Details })
```

Not entirely equivalent (and hardly useful), but OK.

In the URL's you'll see that the second statement is translated to `expand` as well.

---

1. http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/

Comment: What about m:n Relationships? With LinQ you might end up in a Collection at the second dot.